# jQuery (Ajax) does not work, php does not execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need my php code to execute after JavaScipt. I used ajax to to it and it still does not work. My php does not execute.
That is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //generowanie kodu dostępu
  var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var passwordLength = 12;
  var password = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
  }
  document.cookie = "qrpass=" + password;
  //generowanie kodu qr
  new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
    text: password,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  });
  //wrzucanie danych ip i qrpass do bazy danych
  $.ajax({
    url: "admin_qr.php",
    success: function (data) {
      $(".result").html(data);
    },
  });

  //funkcja zamykania okna
  function inform_parent() {
    opener.on_popup_close();
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = inform_parent;
</script>
```

admin_qr.php:

```
<?php
  $password = $_COOKIE['qrpass'];
  echo $password;
?>
```

it shows the text, qrcode but doesn't show $password
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPiMt.png)

how to fix it that it shows the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a case of your relative path (url: "admin_qr.php") not pointing correctly to the php file. Try using your browser's developer tools and the network tab to see if requesting the php file results in a 404 error.